# Can someone give me an easy (or at least grokkable) rule of thumb for how to tell the difference between "this" and "that" and "these" and "those"?

Tags: pronombres, categorías-gramaticales

I had to take the duoLingo "Determiners/1" test about 42 times to get it right; there seems to be no rhyme or reason to it.

Some examples of where I stubbed my toe:

0)"¿Quién bebe de esta taza?"

I tried: Quien bebe de este taza?
Correct answer is: ¿Quién bebe de esta taza?

Is it "esta" instead of "este" because "taza" is feminine, I wondered? But that doesn't seem to be the case, because for this:

1) "Es[e,o] vaso es grande
I tried: "Eso"
but the correct answer is: "Ese"

2) "Esos pájaros no son negros"
I tried: "These birds are not black"
Correct answer is: "Those birds are not black"

I finally got through the test primarily from memorization.

Is this (or that) the actual Montezuma's revenge?

Comment: "This and these have the Ts" covers part of it... "esto and estos" are "this and that"... not sure how much that helps :)

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary? Of course you need memorization: you cannot just guess. Why did you think that *esos* could be translated as *these*? You don't need a rule of thumb. You just need to learn or look up those words in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were right on the first one *Is it "esta" instead of "este" because "taza" is feminine*
But *eso* is not the feminine of *esa*, but *ese* is.

*Eso* is a pronoun not an article, you can't use it to describe the place of a something, *eso* is "the" something.

Ex:

- Échale eso a la carne. (Put that on the meat.)

And for *ese* could  be something like :

- Échale ese condimento a la carne. (Put that seasoner on the meat.)

But the thing is that *eses* doesn't exist and you will have to use *esos* for the plural form, so is something like this:

Esa - that (article feminine)
Ésa - that (pronoun feminine)
Esta - that (article feminine)
Ésta - that (pronoun feminine)
Esas - Those (article feminine plural)
Ésas - Those (pronoun feminine plural)
Estas - These (article feminine plural)
Éstas - These (pronoun feminine plural)

Ese - that (article masculine)
Ése/Eso - that (pronoun masculine/neutral)
Este - this (article masculine)
Éste/Esto - this (pronoun masculine/Neutral)
Esos - those (article masculine plural)
Ésos - those (pronoun masculine plural)
Estos - these (article masculine plural)
Éstos - these (pronoun masculine plural)

Comment: *Eso* and *esto* are not masculine. They are neuter pronouns, never articles, and never have accent. The masculine pronoun for *that* is *ése*. The masculine article and pronoun for *this* are *este* and *éste*.

Comment: Are the forms with "tilde" (éste, ése etc.) still mandatory? I heard that one can now use the forms without "tilde" as pronouns.

Comment: @AlfonsoVillén La tilde ya no es obligatoria, pero se ve mejor :-) Puedes verlo este enlace http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde

Answer (score 3):

`Este` and `Esta` are used, when referring to nearby object, depending on the gender of that object.

> Quien bebe de esta taza?

can never be *"esto"* because `taza` is feminine (la taza).

Now, when you say *"These birds are not black"* you are referring to birds that are near. But in your example you have to translate:

> Esos pájaros no son negros.

which corresponds to birds, that are not that close - *"those birds"*.

With the second example:

> Ese vaso es grande.

`Ese` is correct here, because vaso is masculine (el vaso). `Eso` is neuter and is normally used when the object was already mentioned, or when the gender cannot be determined or when describing an action. Like here:

> Tengo que llamar a mis padres. No olvides eso  
>   I have to call my parents. Don't forget that.  
>   
>   Has hecho un lío. No me gusta eso.  
>   You have done a mess. I don't like this.

Just try and remember that `este/esta/esto/estos/estas` are used for close objects and `ese/eso/esa/esos/esas` for distant ones.

Comment: Tengo que llamar **a** mis padres. No **olvides** eso.
Also, you are mising `este` from your enumeration.

Comment: @rsanchez Thanks for your corrections! I edited the post accordingly.